# Replace year in datetime date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table with a column (`dateDT`), formatted as datetime and a variable input for the year (`@selYear`) in my Select, formatted as int.

How can I replace the year within a date from my table with the variable input and return the result in datetime format (within a Select) ?

**I have tried the following but this returns wrong dates / years:**

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, (@selYear + MONTH(dateDT) + DAY(dateDT))) AS dateDT,
```

**Example:**

```
@selYear = 2014
dateDT = 2010-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

**In this case my result should be:**

```
dateDT = 2014-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) function:

```
DECLARE @selYear VARCHAR(4) = 2014
DECLARE @dateDT DATETIME = '2010-05-02 00:00:00.000'


SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,@selYear - YEAR(@dateDT),@dateDT)
```

---

This is example with smaller then current year:

```
DECLARE @selYear INT = 2009
DECLARE @dateDT DATETIME = '2010-05-02 00:00:00.000'


SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,@selYear - YEAR(@dateDT),@dateDT)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can my @selYear stay as int for this + would this also work with input years in the past (required for the last 5 years) ?

Comment: Yes, it can be `INT` too and yes, you can use `DATEADD` function with negative values of the second parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is great ! I like both answers but go with this one because of the explanations.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) in sqlserver 2012

```
DECLARE @selYear int = 2014
DECLARE @dateDT datetime = '2010-05-02'
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@selYear, 
                     DATEPART(m, @dateDT), 
                     DATEPART(d, @dateDT))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE(dateDT, DATEPART(year, dateDT), @selYear)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great ! Is there no need to convert this to datetime again ?

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is great, too ! I'll try this as well and see what works better / faster.

Comment: Update: I checked and both line take almost the same time to execute while this is slightly faster. If I could then I would accept both answers as there is really no big difference. :)

Comment: This would work for the year but not for month, day etc.  For example, may 5 would turn in to june 6.  So, in this case works great but as a general strategy for adjusting datetimes could create problems